# How to clear the Edit Modal dialog popup form data and update it with new data

Tags: angular, typescript

This piece of code is my Edit button.

The problem here is that I can't fill my Form with correct data which is in other component. Also when I use it the (Edit) button it takes different data, but it doesn't fill my form and stuck with the old data, so I need a help to succeed it.

```
public editUser(user: User): void {
   var id = user.Id;
   localStorage.removeItem("Id");
   localStorage.setItem("Id", id.toString());
   this.userComponent.openModal("custom-modal",user);
};
```

**Here is the other part of code which is in different component from Edit button.:**

```
ngOnInit() {
var id = localStorage.getItem('Id');
localStorage.removeItem('Id');

if (id) {
  this.userService.getById(id).subscribe(res => this.item = res);
  console.log(id);
}

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl(),
    UserName: new FormControl(),
    Password: new FormControl(),
    FirstName: new FormControl(),
    LastName: new FormControl(),
    Email: new FormControl()
  });
}
```

**Picture of the result in browser console after each click on the button.**

[image]

Comment: data is in other component then you need to send the data to the current component using @Output or you can subscribe to a service to get the data and then set it in html

Comment: Use reactive form `.patchValue()` method to fill up your form. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value

Answer (score 0):

To update data in reactive form you have to use `patchValue()`.

```
this.myGroup.patchValue({'FirstName':'John Doe'});
```

It works for me.